# Failable Float to Int conversion in Swift

Tags: swift, math, swift2, integer-arithmetic

I'm trying to find a reliable way to convert a `Float` or a `Double` to an `Int` in Swift. I run into issues when there is an overflow.

Let's take the following example:

```
let double = 9223372036854775807.0 // This is 2^63 - 1 (aka Int.max on 64 bits architecture)

print("Int.max is         : \(Int.max)")
print(String(format: "double value is    : %f", double))
print(String(format: "Double(Int.max) is : %f", Double(Int.max)))

let int: Int
if (double >= Double(Int.max)) {
    print("Warning : double is too big for int !")
    int = Int.max
} else {
    int = Int(double)
}
```

Which prints:

```
 Int.max is         : 9223372036854775807
 double value is    : 9223372036854775808.000000
 Double(Int.max) is : 9223372036854775808.000000
 Warning : double is too big for int !
```

This approach is very cumbersome. Besides, you probably noticed that I test for `double >= Double(Int.max)` and not `double > Double(Int.max)`. That's because `Double(Int.max)` is actually equal to `Int.max + 1` because of rounding. And my code should probably have to be different for 32 bits architectures.

So is there another way? Like a failable initializer that I would have missed or a better, portable way to do this?

Comment: I was just commenting on another thread about this issue. I wish you'd file a bug report with Apple. It's weird how we have overflow operators for Int arithmetic but all we get is a fatal error in this situation. Swift numerics are awful and this is just part of the awfulness...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend `Int` by creating your own failable initializer for `Double`:

```
extension Int {
    init?(double: Double) {
        if double >= Double(Int.max) || double < Double(Int.min) || double.isNaN || double.isInfinite {
            return nil
        } else {
            self = Int(double)
        }
    }
}

if let i = Int(double: 17) {
    print(i)
} else {
    print("nil")
}

// It also handles NaN and Infinite
let nan = sqrt(-1.0)
let inf = 1e1000

Int(double: nan)   // nil
Int(double: inf)   // nil
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for something built-in that would be optimized by the compiler but I guess there is no such thing for now (and I haven't seen anything in Swift 3 either...).

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that this will work as expected with NaNs and infinity.

Comment: Updated answer for NaN and infinity.